# Youtube iframe api not playing video on Edge / IE

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

I need to make a youtube player that has a custom play button and a custom image preview, when clicked both elements (play button and image preview) hide and the video starts to play. I have found the following code online which works fine on Firefox and Chrome but on Edge and IE when you click the play button the elements hide but the video does not play automatically, console displays the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'playVideo'".

Can anyone help me or give me some pointers as my JavaScript is not that great and im going round in circles. Once ive sorted this issues I need adapt the code so that it allows me to have two videos on the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title></title>  

    <style type="text/css">
        button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 106px;
            padding: 12px;
            left: 174px;
        }
        .wrap{
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .videoWrap{
            width: 500px;
            height: 270px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .start-video {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            margin: auto;
            opacity: .3;

            cursor: pointer;

            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        .start-video:hover
        {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-filter: brightness (1);
        }
        iframe{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .thumbnail_container
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #000;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        img.thumbnail
        {
            margin-top: -50px;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="videoWrap">
            <div id="player"></div>
            <div id="thumbnail_container" class="thumbnail_container">
                <img class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" />
            </div>
            <a class="start-video"><img width="64" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/0/375.png" style="filter: invert(100%); -webkit-filter: invert(100%);"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var player;

    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '244',
            width: '434',
            videoId: 'AkyQgpqRyBY',  // youtube video id
            playerVars: {
                'autoplay': 0,
                'rel': 0,
                'showinfo': 0
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log('player ready');
        event.target.playVideo();
    }


    var p = document.getElementById ("player");
    $(p).hide();

    var t = document.getElementById ("thumbnail");
    t.src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/AkyQgpqRyBY/0.jpg";

    onPlayerStateChange = function (event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            $('.start-video').fadeIn('normal');
        }
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.start-video', function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#player").show();
        $("#thumbnail_container").hide();
        player.playVideo();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the orginal fiddle I got the code from, you can see it works in Firefox, Chrome but when viewed in IE and Edge the video wont play on click of the play button - http://jsfiddle.net/BeUFb/326/

Comment: there's a **big** difference between `player.playVideo();` and `event.target.playVideo();` (line 41)

Comment: apologies that's a hangover from me trying everything to get it to work (i'll amend the code above to reflect the fiddle) even so even the fiddle doesn't work on edge and IE, any ideas?

Comment: works fine in Edge ... and IE

Comment: the fiddle? When I view it in edge, I click the play button (which hides the play button and image preview) but then wont auto play the video like it does in Firefox and chrome

Comment: yes, all browsers work - only difference, in IE the image is black for some reason ... is it a png? IE and png == rubbish results :p

Comment: ahh, the colour is because IE doesn't recognise either filter style `filter: invert(100%);` or `-webkit-filter: invert(100%);` - but it definitely works as advertised

Comment: Im so confused as the fiddle for me will not autoplay the youtube video in edge or ie??

Comment: oh, autoplay ... sorry boss!!! that fiddle doesn't autoplay for **any** browser!!!

Comment: For me both Firefox (v50.1.0) and Chrome (v55.0.2883.87 m) autoplay the videos

Comment: How odd ... no autoplay in Firefox (50.1.0 or 52) nor Chrome (55.0.2883.87 m) - all are 64bit versions, if that makes a difference ... you don't happen to have any add-ons that autoplay youtube videos do you?

Comment: Not that im aware of. Ive since found another fiddle which seems to do what I need (with two videos too) and the fiddle works in edge yay! but as soon as I paste the code locally edge doesn't even seem to register the click (on the image) **bangs head on the desk!** http://jsfiddle.net/KtbYR/5/

Comment: Of course, the lack of autoplay issue in chrome and firefox may be my end :p